# iTerm2: open link under cursor (in vim)

Tags: vim, iterm2

I can command-click to open a url from iTerm2 in my Chrome browser. For example:

[image]

However, I would like to be able to open the link directly from a keyboard shortcut without having to click on it. For example if my cursor is here:

[image]

To be able to do something like <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> to be able to open that link directly (from within vim). How could I do that in iTerm2?

Comment: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Open_a_web-browser_with_the_URL_in_the_current_line Found in https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Special:Search?query=open+browser+url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you ever tried using `gx` in normal mode? Because the function of "gx" is exactly for this purpose.

In my case I set my default browser with a specific profile I have created:

```
:let g:netrw_browsex_viewer= "firefox -P user"
```

Where "user" represents your current user

Comment: thank you, that's perfect! It seems to work for files (without a space or any escape character in it...) but for urls it's trying to open with `wget`. How do I change this to open with my default browser, Chrome in this case?

Comment: Seems to work when I just do `:!open https://trello.com/b/abc`, so how to do that in `gx` ?

Comment: You can use on your vimrc: `let g:netrw_browsex_viewer= "firefox -P user"
` in my case "firefox" but you can see on help `:h netrw` [@David542](https://stackoverflow.com/users/651174/david542).

Answer (score 0):

I use a this plugin which will allow me to system copy (from the beginning of the link) using `cp$` then ctrl tab and paste into a new tab on my browser.

`Plug 'christoomey/vim-system-copy'`

Might not be the solution you were looking for but it works well for me!